# Heroku slug size exploded after rails asset precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app was running just file. I had to add an additional js file and after recompiling assets and redeploying it went to 930Mb so it won't deploy on Heroku. I've tried clearing assets, clearing build cache and anything else I've found but it's only down to 821 Mb. I'm out of ideas and I'm stuck. I needed to deploy this to fix a bug but the size just won't budge.

The vendor folder is currently huge at 711 Mb. How can I reduce it's size?

`~ $ du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr`

```
821M    /app
711M    /app/vendor
79M     /app/bin
27M     /app/public
2.4M    /app/app
964K    /app/latest.dump
520K    /app/server
520K    /app/generate
268K    /app/config
188K    /app/db
164K    /app/spec
104K    /app/lib
48K     /app/jquery.fileupload.js
48K     /app/Gemfile.lock
20K     /app/widget.js
20K     /app/esc
16K     /app/.heroku
12K     /app/.profile.d
8.0K    /app/tmp
8.0K    /app/spring
8.0K    /app/exit
8.0K    /app/.bundle
4.0K    /app/.ruby-version
4.0K    /app/.rspec
4.0K    /app/README.MD
4.0K    /app/Rakefile~
4.0K    /app/Rakefile
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/log
4.0K    /app/jdd
4.0K    /app/init.rb~
4.0K    /app/init.rb
4.0K    /app/.gitignore~
4.0K    /app/.gitignore
4.0K    /app/Gemfile~
4.0K    /app/Gemfile
4.0K    /app/config.ru
```

Comment: You can see vendor folder has taken 711. It might be some Gem within vendor nested folder(or something else). You can now look inside vendor folder (and nested folder) using `du -ha --max-depth 1 /app/vendor | sort -hr` until you find the folder taking space

Answer (score 0):

Except the vendor older folders look fine. Check if the content in vendor, generally installed gems being sent out as **bundle pack** along the project folder. If that's the case, it can be removed.

You can compress the js,css and other asset files further using different libraries and compression techniques. Also after compression the files can be made accessible from content storing platforms like s3.